# airmon ng ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, security, windows-subsystem-for-linux, airmon-ng, aircrack-ng

Im using ubuntu bionic (UBUNTU
WSL)

I can't use airmon-ng!

It throws the following

```
ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory
```

I checked [airmon-ng: ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306836/airmon-ng-ls-cannot-access-sys-class-ieee80211-no-such-file-or-directory) no fix

iwconfig

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

eth2      no wireless extensions.

eth3      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wifi0     no wireless extensions.

wifi1     no wireless extensions.
```

I have a wifi card and latest aircrack-ng, no fix

airmon-ng check kill

```
ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory
```

this is the output

airmon-ng wifi0

```
ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory


PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset
```

the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSL does not have a real Linux kernel. It is an emulation of the Linux services on top of the Windows HAL.

As such low level utilities such as `airmon-ng` won't work. I also have honest doubts `iwconfig` will fully work - the WiFi/network configuration is done on the Windows side.

For more details, see [SSH In Windows 10 Bash(Ubuntu)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474594/ssh-in-windows-10-bashubuntu/474604#47460) and [Attempting to run a regular tunnel in Debian version 9.5 Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457454/attempting-to-run-a-regular-tunnel-in-debian-version-9-5-linux/457462#457462)