# Airmon-ng not working on Crostini

Tags: chrome-os, chrome-book, airmon-ng, aircrack-ng

When I try running `airmon-ng` I get no output and this error:
`ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory`

This is on a linux terminal on my Pixelbook, I installed aircrack-ng using **Katoolin**.

I had a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306836/airmon-ng-ls-cannot-access-sys-class-ieee80211-no-such-file-or-directory?newreg=5c4e9d19841d45bab9e2eb2d75da65b8) but the answer doesn't apply to ChromeOS.

running `iwconfig` gives me:

```
lo         no wireless extensions.

eth0       no wireless extensions.
```